# How to install Teradata Parallel Trasport client in linux machine?

Tags: teradata, informatica

How to install Teradata PT client in linux machine. Which software needs to install ? Have any pre setup required? Is informatica server required for TPT client?

Comment: See https://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-linux-installation-package-0

Comment: @dnoeth . do we need to install informatica server where tpt run..

Comment: There is a "tbuild" command-line utility to run TPT, as well as the API that Informatica would use. See the [TPT Reference](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/G4kxgNoyXX8P5vWrFMmibA/BUmrvOl1xhB6eS_Rq7BX0Q)

Comment: Is there any reference for run TPT via API?

Comment: Not sure.. but have option to run from CLI